# How do I get an input from a user with the JavaCord discord api

Tags: java, discord

I'm kinda new to java and to the Stack Overflow community and im trying to make a discord bot that can take mod applications for my discord server. but for that i need to take an input from the user and then be able to send that in an embed form to a specific channel so if anyone can help it'll be kindly appreciated

I'm using the Javacord Discord api for this as i find it easier and more straightforward

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out the wiki at:

https://javacord.org/wiki/getting-started/writing-your-first-bot.html#log-the-bot-in

This explains how to get a basic command from a user. To send a message to a specific channel will also be in there. When starting out using any library i would always check the documentation if you have any questions/issues.

Hope this is useful.
Have fun :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways, the easiest is adding an AddMessageCreateListener. Here is an example:

```
api.addMessageCreateListener(event -> {

            if (event.getMessageContent().startsWith("say ")) {
                String message = event.getMessageContent();
                message = message.replaceAll("say","");
                event.getChannel().sendMessage(message);

            }
        });
```

This would, whenever a user says a message that starts with 'say ', store the message content in a temporary String `message`, and remove the word 'say '. The bot will then send the message in the same channel as the original message.